# Swift optional parameters in implementation of Binary Search

Tags: swift

I want to write a nice implementation of Binary Search in Swift and the following seems like a hack to overcome passing the lower and upper bound in all cases.

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int? = 0, _ upperBound: Int? = 0) -> Int? {
    var ub = upperBound
    if (ub == 0 ) { ub = arr.count
}
```

In depth explanation: I've written a set of tests of the form:
`XCTAssertEqual(binarySearch(arr: [1,2,3,4], target: 5), nil)`

and I do not want to pass the lower and upper bound into the binary search in the first instance.

My function header looks like:

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int? = 0, _ upperBound: Int? = 0) -> Int? {
```

in every recursive call of binary search the lower bound will either be zero, or the passed parameter and this makes sense. But the upper bound does not.

Now I'd like to write something like

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int? = 0, _ upperBound: arr.count) -> Int? {
```

but clearly this is not possible.

I would even like to add the following (but clearly can't, as upperBound is a let constant):

```
if (upperBound == 0 ) {upperBound = arr.count}
```

I'd love to use:

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int? = 0, _ var upperBound: Int? = 0) -> Int? {
```

but looks like this is no longer a feature in swift.

Am I left with having to use an extra variable as follows, because this is a mess!

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int? = 0, _ upperBound: Int? = 0) -> Int? {
    var ub = upperBound
    if (ub == 0 ) {ub = arr.count}
```

Comment: FYI - it makes little sense to combine a non-nil default argument value with an optional argument, especially when you will never actually pass nil to the parameter.

Comment: You should not use 2 separate lower/upper ints like this. Swift has fantastic first-class ranges. Use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the upper bound parameter optional (as you are) but set the default to `nil`. Then you create your local `ub` value as:

```
let ub = upperbound ?? arr.count
```

The lower bound should be non-optional with a default of `0`.

```
func binarySearch(arr: [Int], target: Int, _ lowerBound: Int = 0, _ upperBound: Int? = nil) -> Int? {
    let ub = upperBound ?? arr.count
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation. A recursive function's signature might need more parameters than its entry point. The best way to handle this is to use a nested function.

```
func binarySearch(_ array: [Int], for target: Int) -> Int? {
    func binarySearch(_ array: [Int], for: Int, lowerBound: Int, upperBound: Int) -> Int? {
        // your implementation here
    }

    return binarySearch(array, for: target, lowerBound: 0, upperBound: array.count)
}
```

For more Swifty code, I suggest you convert you try using:

- An extension, rather than a free function that uses a parameter for what is effectively "self"
- A range instead of 2 seperate `Int`s
- A public entry point with minimal parameters, and a private recursive function will all necessary parameters for the recursion.

Here's an example to get started:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Self.IndexDistance == Int {
    public func binarySearch(for target: Element) -> Int? {
        return binarySearch(for: target, inRange: 0 ..< self.count)
    }

    private func binarySearch(for target: Element, inRange range: CountableRange<Int>) -> Int? {
        return nil // Your implementation here
    }
}
```